# Purple lighting and reflections Blender 3.6

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm creating a scene in blender using cycles, I recently upgraded from 3.4 to 3.6 for the sim nodes but the scene is just purple.
[image: outisde of scene]

The floor is reflective and isn't using a texture and all nodes are configured properly. (I think)

[image: View from inside the bubble]

this is how the scene is configured inside

I dont think its a texture glitch because the only thing that has an uploaded texture is the skybox, and it was properly UV wrapped and the texture is fine.

Thanks ahead of time.